# ¿Qué valor contiene argv[0]?

Tags: c

El `argv[0]` de un programa desarrollado en C, ¿es el propio ejecutable? Viendo este código me surgió esa pregunta:

```
int main(int argc, unsigned char *argv[])
{
    char *mynameis = "nombre/cfg";
    if(SERVER_LIST_SIZE <= 0) return 0;
    printf("construir %s\n", contruir());
    strncpy(argv[0],"",strlen(argv[0]));
}
```

Comment: Buenas @G.A.P, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Sin ánimo de ofender, pero creo que esta pregunta sería muy fácil de responder por uno mismo y sería más instructivo para ti mismo. Quiero decir, imprimiendo con un printf el contenido ya lo estarías viendo.

Te lo digo con ánimo de hacer una crítica positiva. Porque a mi me ayudó mucho en mis inicios y todavía lo hace, intentar entender cómo funcionan las cosas más básicas por mi mismo.

De todas formas ya te han respondido a la pregunta. Un saludo!

Answer (score 4):

Sí, el primer argumento de `argv` será el nombre del programa. Al menos así se especifica en el [estándar de C](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html) (traducción mía, reducida):

> **5.1.2.2.1 Inicio de programa**
>
> [...]
>
> 169 — El valor de `argc` debe ser no negativo
>
> [...]
>
> 171 — Si el valor de `argc` es mayor que cero, los miembros del array `argv[0]` a `argv[argc-1]` (ambos incluidos) deberán contener punteros a cadenas, que tienen dados valores definidos en implementación por el entorno en el que se ejecuta el programa antes del inicio del programa.
>
> [...]
>
> 174 — Si el valor de `argc` es mayor que cero, la cadena apuntada por `argv[0]` representará el nombre del programa;
>
> 175 — `argv[0][0]` debe ser el carácter `null` si el nombre del programa no está disponible o no ha sido provisto por el entorno de ejecución del programa.

Con lo cual `argv[0]` debe contener el nombre del programa o + el valor `null` si éste no está disponible (aunque no conozco ninguna plataforma o situación en la que esto último ocurra).

---

Para más información, puedes consultar los siguientes enlaces (en inglés):

- [Estándar C (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)
- [Stack Overflow: Can argv[0] contain an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8665439/3695983)
- [Stack Overflow: When can argv[0] have null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2794150/3695983)